# Parallel execution of multi-threaded program in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I want to write a program using multi-threading approach where each thread does some IO operation and each IO operation takes 100ms to complete. My problem is I want to design my problem such a way that as soon as a thread calls to IO operation and goes to waiting state, rest of the thread should start their execution.

Here is my initial experiment:

```
public class TestThread {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            Future<String> future = executorService.submit(() -> {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
                return getValue();
               //here instead of calling getValue(), thread will call some IO operation
//each IO call is indepndent of each other
            });
            list.add(future.get());
        }
       }
    static String getValue() throws InterruptedException {
        if(Thread.currentThread().getId() == 11)
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        return "some value for the thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId();
    }
}
```

Here is what observed: 
Thread number 12 waits until thread number 11 finishes its execution. What I want here is, as soon as thread no 11 goes to sleep state(in actual problem it will go to IO waiting) thread no 12 should start its execution.
Please help me designing this problem.

Comment: What? Please try to restate your problem.

Comment: You have a fixed thread pool. Of course it's going to wait. I the thread pool is less than the # of threads, it will block.

Answer (score 0):

> Thread number 12 waits until thread number 11 finishes its execution

This may be because you are adding each task in a loop, which you might think will *fire and forget* in an asynchronous style, however you are effectively blocking the launch of sucessive tasks by calling `future.get()` and the end of the loop.

`future.get()` is blocking and hence Thread 11 is preventing Thread 12 from being launched.

*I propose this design, to avoid blocking yourself*

```
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListeningExecutorService;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

public class TestThread {

    public static List<Integer> execute(ExecutorService executorService, Callable<Integer> callable, int calls)
        throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        ListeningExecutorService listeningExecutorService = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(executorService);

        List<ListenableFuture<Integer>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < calls; i++) {
            futures.add(listeningExecutorService.submit(callable));
        }

        return Futures.allAsList(futures).get();
    }
}
```

I suggest that if the IO calls are independent of each other then why encourage them to wait on each other? And why would they produce a combined list of any sort?